# What is the order of execution, when calling an instantiation method, in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

In my `GameManager` script, I instantiate a player game object, and call another method like this:

```
void Start()
{
   Debug.Log("GameManager Start() called...");
   Instantiate(player, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
   InitNewLevel();
}

void InitNewLevel()
{
    Debug.Log("GameManager InitNewLevel() called...");
}
```

In my `Player` script, I have this:

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Player Start() called...");
}
```

---

I was expecting `Player.Start()` to be called after the `Instantiate(player, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);` line, and before the `InitNewLevel()`. However, if I look at my debug log output, I see this:

> GameManager Start() called...
>   GameManager InitNewLevel() called...
>   Player Start() called...

Why do my methods execute in this order? Why does `Player.Start()` get called *after* `GameManager.InitNewLevel`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The order is:

1. `Instantiate` or `AddComponent` called by our spawning method
2. `Awake()` <-- You can think of this like a "Constructor" for MonoBehaviours
3. `OnEnable()`, skipped if script is disabled in prefab or GameObject is inactive
4. `Instantiate` or `AddComponent` return and the calling method continues executing

As Gnemlock points out, Start will get called later after the calling method has completed (if the script & its gameObject are enabled/active), but before the newly-spawned script instance gets its first Update or FixedUpdate, ie...

5. (Sometime later) `Start()`
6. `FixedUpdate()`, skipped if there's no physics tick this frame (short frame), or called multiple times we tick multiple times this frame (long frame)
7. `Update()`
8. `LateUpdate()`

Here's a script you can use to test & verify this yourself:

```
public class InstantiatorTest : MonoBehaviour {

    static bool hasSpawned;

    // Editor-only, zeroth for objects already in the scene.
    void OnValidate()
    {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " Validated");
    }

    // First!
    void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " Awake");
    }

    // Second!
    void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " Enabled");
    }

    // Third!
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " Start");

        if (!hasSpawned)
        {
            hasSpawned = true;

            var go = new GameObject("spawned");
            go.AddComponent<InstantiatorTest>();

            Debug.Log("Spawn returned.");
        }
    }

    // Fourth! (If enough time has elapsed)
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " Fixed");
    }

    // Fifth!
    void Update () {
        Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " Update");
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [this answer, which gives additional suggestions for ways to control the ordering of your script's activities](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/115597/39518).